# How can I make LibGDX detect only a single tap/click?

Tags: android, macos, libgdx

I'm trying to do a basic counter, so every tap will increase a counter by one. I can get the counter to work but it's also increasing the count crazily when I hold down my finger/click.

**Code:**

```
public void render() {
    boolean isTouched = Gdx.input.isTouched();

    if (isTouched) {
        System.out.println(Cash);
        Cash++;

    }

}
```

Also, while I'm here, how can you print an `integer/float` that will change every tap?

Like: `font.draw(batch, Cash, 300, 260);`

Straight up don't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing is polling the Input. But for what you want, an [InputProcessor](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html) would be the way to go:

```
public class MyInputProcessor implements InputProcessor {
   @Override
   public boolean keyDown (int keycode) {
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean keyUp (int keycode) {
      cash++; //<----
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean keyTyped (char character) {
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean touchDown (int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean touchUp (int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean touchDragged (int x, int y, int pointer) {
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean touchMoved (int x, int y) {
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean scrolled (int amount) {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Set it in your create code:

```
MyInputProcessor inputProcessor = new MyInputProcessor();
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputProcessor);
```

Reference: [Libgdx Wiki Event-Handling](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling)

> how can you print an integer/float that will change every tap?
>   Like: font.draw(batch, Cash, 300, 260);
>   Straight up don't work.

[BitmapFont#draw](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.html#draw%28com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20float,%20float%29) accepts a String, not an int/float. You must use one of these:

```
Integer.toString(Cash); //or
Float.toString(Cash);
```

**Pro Tip:** Don't start a variable name with Caps. it should be `cash`.

Answer (score 4):

The `InputProcessor` is definitely the way to go longer term (event-based input is more robust, I think), but a built-in hack you can also use is the ["justTouched" API](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html#justTouched%28%29):

```
if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
    System.out.println(Cash);
    Cash++;
}
```

See https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/InputPolling

Comment: Thats true, I forgot to mention it. By the way I sometimes end up using InputPolling when multitouch is a must (example: a platformer). I got so many weird touchdowns/ups everywhere with the processor which is probably for bad hardware or android problem, which is quite common.